# send custom emails to cutomers with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, php-7, laravel-5.8

I have customer data in my database with their emails. In my case, i want to get user email from customer table and send a custom email to customer. I'm new to laravel and this is the very first time i'm working with laravel notification. Help me to do this!

I have created this SendMailController:

```html
    public function sendNotifications(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        
        $customer_id = DB::table('jobs')->select('customers_id')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
        $customer_email = DB::table('customer')->select('email')->where('id', '=', $customer_id)->get();
        $customer_firstname = DB::table('customer')->select('firstname')->where('id', '=', $customer_id)->get();

       sendEmail($customer_firstname, $customer_email);

 
       return view('admin.sendNotifications');
    }
```

I have created a sendEmail Notification class:

```html
class sendEmail extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct($customer_firstname, $customer_email)
    {
        $this->customer_email = $customer_email;
        $this->customer_firstname = $customer_firstname;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->error()
                    ->subject('Thank you!')
                    ->from('hashankannangara@gmail.com', 'Sender')
                    ->to($this->customer_email)
                    ->line($this->customer_firstname.''.'Thanks for got services from us!');
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

How can i pass the customer email to to() function? I want to display customer first name in email with Thanking them. How can i use a custom template and add to this email? I appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications#mail-notifications

You can use something like this in toMail method:

```
return (new CustomMail($this->customer))->to($this->customer->email);
```

and when you call notify you must pass a customer

Comment: I have edited my code. Is that correct? i did something like yours.

Comment: is that working? maybe it would be a best if you create a dedicate mail class for that

Comment: no i have a error. `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` in SendMailController

Comment: you don't call notify in controller. you just type sendEmail. find cutomer and then call it like this $cutomer->notify(new SendEmail($customer))

Comment: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` this error occurs fot that reason?

Comment: do you import  sendEmail class in controller?

Comment: `use App\Notifications\sendEmail;` yh. like this, correct?

Comment: `Argument 1 passed to notify() must be of the type string or null` this error occures now

Comment: pass a $customer object instead of string like name or surname

Comment: `$user->notify( new sendEmail($customer_firstname, $customer_email));` i added this, `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::to()` this error occured. how to set recipient email?

Comment: you don't have public property $customer_email in sendEmail class

Comment: I don't understand, can u continue with a chat?

Answer (score 0):

**use Mail;**

```
$data = 'set data variable pass in view' 
$email= 'receiver' email'

Mail::send('here set your file for view (ex. email.access(blade))', $data, function ($message) use ($email) {
        $message->from('sender mail','Title')->subject('Register');
        $message->to($email);
    });
```